# why I cannot remount the /system as rw?

Tags: root-access

I got a device with Stock ROM with android 4.2.2 without root yet. I got into adb shell with #. I successfully did 'mount -o rw,remount /'. However, when I try to do 'mount -o rw,remount /system'. It said read-only filesystem. In mount I can see the`emmc@android` mounted at /system as ext4, which is actually a device called /dev/block/mmcblk0p5.

```
/emmc@android /system ext4 ro,relatime,noauto_da_alloc,commit=1,data=ordered 0 0
```

Here is its tune2fs result:

```
 # tune2fs -l /dev/block/mmcblk0p5
 tune2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
 Filesystem volume name:   <none>
 Last mounted on:          /system
 Filesystem UUID:          57f8f4bc-abf4-0000-675f-946fc0f9f25b
 Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
 Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
 Filesystem features:      has_journal resize_inode filetype needs_recovery extent sparse_super large_file
 Filesystem flags:         unsigned_directory_hash 
 Default mount options:    (none)
 Filesystem state:         clean with errors
 Errors behavior:          Remount read-only
 Filesystem OS type:       Linux
 Inode count:              44802
 Block count:              179194
 Reserved block count:     0
 Free blocks:              40901
 Free inodes:              43179
 First block:              0
 Block size:               4096
 Fragment size:            4096
 Reserved GDT blocks:      47
 Blocks per group:         32768
 Fragments per group:      32768
 Inodes per group:         7467
 Inode blocks per group:   467
 Last mount time:          Fri Oct 21 04:11:22 2016
 Last write time:          Sat Oct 15 19:28:31 2016
 Mount count:              49
 Maximum mount count:      -1
 Last checked:             Wed Jul 20 19:51:30 2016
 Check interval:           0 (<none>)
 Lifetime writes:          94 MB
 Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
 Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
 First inode:              11
 Inode size:               256
 Required extra isize:     28
 Desired extra isize:      28
 Journal inode:            8
 Default directory hash:   tea
 Journal backup:           inode blocks
 FS Error count:           5
 First error time:         Fri Oct 21 04:11:24 2016
 First error function:     ext4_init_inode_table
 First error line #:       1156
 First error inode #:      0
 First error block #:      0
 Last error time:          Fri Oct 21 04:28:29 2016
 Last error function:      ext4_remount
 Last error line #:        4269
 Last error inode #:       0
 Last error block #:       0
```

It has 5 errors which probably my attempt to do remount. I try to boot into recovery mode. But it does not have adb access. So I cannot do e2fsck. Any suggestion about what should I try to get it mount as rw?

Comment: You'll need root for that. Than in shell type "su" (without quotes), grant root for adb on phone and than use "mount -o rw,remount /system"

Comment: I've already in root shell. I do not need su at all at this point. I do want to push `su` in to /system/bin. This is not privilege problem since I can change / and any other dir/file permission without any problem.